# In a velocity-time graph, if the velocity is negative and the slope is negative, is it still accelerating?

Tags: calculus

So in a velocity-time graph, a negative velocity means the speed in the opposite direction. So from -10 m/s to -30 m/s, it is accelerating in the opposite direction. However the slope is negative, so is it still accelerating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with the word 'accelerating', which might not align with how you think about it intuitively. Suppose we define the positive direction as moving to the right. Then, moving to the left means that you have a negative velocity. Hence, saying that we are going from $-10 \mathrm{m/s}$ from $-30 \mathrm{m/s}$ is a shorthand for 'at first, we were moving at $10$ metres per second to the left; now, we are moving at $30$ metres per second to the left'. Hence, the *speed* of the car has increased, since $30>10$. However, the velocity, which tells us not just the speed, but the direction in which the speed is acting, has *decreased* from $-10\mathrm{m/s}$ to $-30\mathrm{m/s}$. Since acceleration is measure of the change in velocity, not speed, over this time period the car has experienced negative acceleration. This is despite the fact that the car is now moving faster.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To illustrate take a simple example with velocity $v<0$ during $0<t<1.5 $

$$ v=t^2- 3t$$

the acceleration

$$ a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}=2 t-3\;<0 \text{ which is decelerating in the above interval.}$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A physicist would use the word "accelerating" to mean the change in velocity, whether positive or negative, i.e. whether speeding up or slowing down.